# Formatar Campo C#

Tags: c#, string, formatação

Conheço as formatações 'N' e 'C' do C#, mas elas não me atendem.

Eu recebo `1000` do banco de dados e gostaria que formatasse para `1.000`.

O que eu coloco no

```
.ToString("???")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Só usar a formatação `n`, seguido da quantidade de casas decimais.

Você pode ver todas as possibilidades em [cadeias de caracteres de formato numérico personalizado, na MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx).

Usando o `.ToString()` mesmo fica assim:

```
numero.ToString("n0");
```

Perceba que o formato vai ser sensível à cultura da aplicação. Então pode ser interessante definir uma cultura específica.

Atente que a classe `CultureInfo` está no namespace `System.Globalization`, provavelmente será preciso incluí-lo no código (`using System.Globalization`).

```
numero.ToString("n0", new CultureInfo("pt-BR"));
```

---

Se estiver usando C# 6, pode usar assim

```
$"{numero:n0}"
```

Caso esteja com uma versão anterior

```
string.Format("{0:n0}", numero);
```

---

Exemplo:

[Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/B83ZPK)

```
using System.Globalization;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int numero = 50000;

        // Com string interpolation (C# 6)
        Console.WriteLine($"{numero:n0}");

        // Com string.Format
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:n0}", numero));
        // -- Definindo a cultura
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format(new CultureInfo("pt-BR"), "{0:n0}", numero));

        // Com ToString()
        Console.WriteLine(numero.ToString("n0"));
        // -- Definindo a cultura
        Console.WriteLine(numero.ToString("n0", new CultureInfo("pt-BR")));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar assim:

```
1000.ToString("0,0",new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(("pt-BR")));
```

Neste caso você precisa passar a instância de `CultureInfo` de pt-BR para ele formatar no padrão brasileiro, caso contrário ele formata no padrão americano

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o seguinte:

```
   int retorno = Convert.ToInt32("1000");
   string.Format("{0:0,0}", retorno);
```